# Excel VBA: Connect Scrollbar and Textbox in Userform

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, scrollbar, userform

I have a userform with a scrollbar and textbox.

How do you code it so that the scrollbar connects to the textbox?

For example, I want the textbox to increase/decrease by a value each time you click the up/down-arrow on the scrollbar.

Comment: @paulbica - I think you're confusing the textbox scrolling text bar with the spinner/scrollbar controls used to increment/decrement values

Comment: @dbmitch, yes, didn't read the question carefully...

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of Excel you are using so see if this works for you.

To get a spinner or scrollbar to work you can connect it to a cell by right-clicking on the scroll bar control and selecting `Properties | Format Control | Control` and then select the cell by using the `Cell Link` property at the bottom to select and link the cell you want to increment/decrement by using the scrollbar

If you haven't already linked the textbox to that cell, you can do so by

- First - select the text box
- Second - put your cursor in the formula bar
- Third - type in `=` symbol and then click on the above cell you want
  to link to,
- Finally - press the Enter key